# populate dropdown by ajax from a django queryset

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a query to pic items from a table in django as follows

```
items  = EvidenceList.objects.values('evidence').distinct()
```

Now i want to have the items displayed in a dropdown at the front end.
here is how I make the dropdown

```
<select name="evidence_selected" id="evidence_selected" style="margin-right:20px;color:#5c89db;margin-top:20px;margin-left:40px;height: 2em;border-radius: 3px;">

<option value="selectedvidence" id="selectedvidence"name="selectedvidence">Select Evidence Number</option>
<option id="new"value="new">New</option>
{% for item in items %}
<option value="{{item.evidence}}">{{ item.evidence }}</option>
{% endfor %}    
</select>
```

I opt to get this values by making an ajax call to the functions as follows

```
function CallAjax(DataHandle) {
     return $.ajax({
          url: "/get_evidence_items/",
          type: "post",
          success: function(data){
               DataHandle(data);
          }
     });
}
$("#evidence_selected").click(function(){
    CallAjax(function(output){
       items=output
});    

});
```

If i do `alert(items)` I can be able to see the items.
My problem is how do I append the Items to my dropdown where I have

```
{% for item in items %}
<option value="{{item.evidence}}">{{ item.evidence }}</option>

{% endfor %}
```

Given that I can only access the items within the success function(if I am right,not sure).
Any insights or/and example based on my description will be highly regarded.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way I have found is to utilise the ModelChoiceField widget render method. It will make all the markup you need. Then simply add that directly to the select.html.

```
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField


    markup = ModelChoiceField(queryset=items).widget.render(value="pk_evidencelist", name="evidence")
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({'results': markup}),mimetype="application/json")
```

Then in your success handler:

```
$("#evidence_selected").html(data.results)
```

Also remember to set your return data type to json.

Comment: where do we import ModelChoiceField from?

Comment: when I click on the items they dont get selected..what if i want the first option to be always "new"? guide on the issues pls